# Segmented control and Tableview control

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have three differente kind of tableview,
how can I used segmented control to switch to difference tableview?

Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    tableData1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"a", @"b", @"c", @"d", @"e", @"f",@"a", @"b", @"c", @"d", @"e", @"f", nil];
    tableData2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"c", @"d", @"e", @"f",@"a", @"b", @"c", @"d", @"e", @"f",@"a", @"b", nil];

    thumbnails1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"a.png", @"b.png", @"c.png", @"d.png", @"e.png", @"f.png",@"a.png", @"b.png", @"c.png", @"d.png", @"e.png", @"f.png", nil];
    thumbnails2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"d.png", @"e.png", @"f.png",@"a.png", @"b.png", @"c.png",@"a.png", @"b.png", @"c.png", @"d.png", @"e.png", @"f.png", nil];

}
```

and in tableview delegate:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    if (self.seg.selectedSegmentIndex==0) {
        return [tableData1 count];

    }
    else if(self.seg.selectedSegmentIndex==1)
    {
        return [tableData2 count];
    }

    }
    return [tableData1 count];
            }


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"TableViewCell";

    TableViewCell *cell = (TableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    if (self.seg.selectedSegmentIndex==0)
    {
        cell.nameLabel.text=[tableData1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.thumbnailImageView.image = [thumbnails1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    }
    else if(self.seg.selectedSegmentIndex==1)
    {
        cell.nameLabel.text=[tableData2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
         cell.thumbnailImageView.image = [thumbnails2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    }      
    return cell;
}
```

in DidSelectRow part:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    DetailViewController *detail = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];


    if (self.seg.selectedSegmentIndex==0)
    {
        [detail setTitle:[tableData1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        detail.DetailLabel.text = [tableData1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        detail.DetailImage.image = [thumbnails1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    }
    else if(self.seg.selectedSegmentIndex==1)
    {
        [detail setTitle:[tableData2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        detail.DetailLabel.text = [tableData2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        detail.DetailImage.image = [thumbnails2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    }

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

i edited the code...you made many little mistakes...this is the code that you excatly needed...

homePage.h

```
  #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

  @interface homePage : UIViewController

  @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *seg;
  @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *table;
  @property (nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray*tabledata1;
  @property (nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray*tabledata2;
  @property (nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray*thumbnails1;
  @property (nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray*thumbnails2;
  - (IBAction)segment:(id)sender;

  @end
```

homepage.m

```
  @implementation homePage
  @synthesize tabledata1,tabledata2,thumbnails1,thumbnails2;


  - (void)viewDidLoad
  {
      [super viewDidLoad];
      // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

      tabledata1=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"a", @"b", @"c", @"d", @"e", @"f",@"a", @"b", @"c", @"d", @"e", @"f", nil];

      tabledata2=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"c", @"d", @"e", @"f",@"a", @"b", @"c", @"d", @"e", @"f",@"a", @"b", nil];


      thumbnails1=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"a.jpg", @"b.jpg", @"c.jpg", @"d.jpg", @"e.jpg", @"f.jpg",@"a.jpg", @"b.jpg", @"c.jpg", @"d.jpg", @"e.jpg", @"f.jpg", nil];

      thumbnails2=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"d.jpg", @"e.jpg", @"f.jpg",@"a.jpg", @"b.jpg", @"c.jpg",@"a.jpg", @"b.jpg", @"c.jpg", @"d.jpg", @"e.jpg", @"f.jpg", nil];

    }

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        if (self.seg.selectedSegmentIndex==0)
          {
              return [tabledata1 count];

          }
        else
          {

               return [tabledata2 count];


           }

           return [tabledata1 count];

     }

     - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
     {
       static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";

       TableViewCell *cell = (TableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
       if (cell == nil)
       {
           NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SimpleTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
           cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        }

     if (self.seg.selectedSegmentIndex==0) {

      cell.thumbnailImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[thumbnails1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
      cell.nameLabel.text=[tabledata1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
     }
      else if(self.seg.selectedSegmentIndex==1)
     {

       cell.thumbnailImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[thumbnails2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
       cell.nameLabel.text=[tabledata2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

      }


       return cell;
     }   


     - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
     {


       detailPage*detail=[[detailPage alloc]init];


       if (self.seg.selectedSegmentIndex==0)
       {


        detail.DetailLabel_string=[tabledata1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        detail.DetailImage_string=[thumbnails1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];



       }
       else if(self.seg.selectedSegmentIndex==1)
       {


        detail.DetailLabel_string=[tabledata2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        detail.DetailImage_string=[thumbnails2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];



       }

         [self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];

     }

 - (IBAction)segment:(id)sender 
    {
       [self.table reloadData];
    }
```

detailPage.h

```
  #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

  @interface detailPage : UIViewController


  @property(nonatomic,retain)NSString*DetailLabel_string;
  @property(nonatomic,retain)NSString*DetailImage_string;
    // and also synthesis this two string its necessary.
  @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *tittlelbl;
  @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageview;
  @end
```

detailpage.m

```
   - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
         [super viewDidLoad];
         // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

         NSLog(@"%@",DetailImage_string);
         NSLog(@"%@",DetailLabel_string);

         self.tittlelbl.text=DetailLabel_string;
        self.imageview.image=[UIImage imageNamed:DetailImage_string];
     }
```

its totally work for me....i did same thing that u may be want....n also care for custom cell......

Comment: it didn't work, i can't get any data( include the fist data) now when i used this method.

Comment: in my project its work perfectlty, may be problem at else where

Comment: how about if i not only show label text, and with image also,and i used NSMutableArray Also,is that happen make something wrong?

Comment: it doesn't matter in my example i took static cell...instead of it you might be  took custom cell....but concept of implementing table data with using segment cotroller is as per above that i show...

Comment: i edited my code ...as u wanted.....little change that i make..you used .png images instead of it i used .jpg ....otherwise totally code like yours...best of luck

Comment: i got this error message :
'Could not load NIB in bundle:'NSBundle </Users/MyName/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/75DA86A7-5F3C-49C7-A920-53F6EEC899BC/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/82EA07D8-9293-4323-98D0-86BB924A4AB1/TNT.app> (loaded)' with name 'SimpleTableCell''

did my table cell got something wrong?

Comment: you might be give the different name to your cell identifier...it must be same as your class name ...that you gives to the table cell